# Interromper um Thread específica

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço para interromper uma thread específica? por exemplo:

```
from _thread import *
from time import sleep
result = 0

def soma(nome, numero, delay):
global result
while True:
    result += numero
    print('{}: {} '.format(nome, result))
    sleep(delay)

start_new_thread(soma,('Th 1', 1, 3))
start_new_thread(soma,('Th 2', 1, 1))

while True:
    pass
```

Como eu faria, por exemplo, para interromper a Th2 e deixar a Th1 sendo executada? ou vice-versa

Comment: Quando você diz interromper se refere à terminar sua `execução` ou `deletá-la`?

Comment: Deleta-la, mas ou terminar sua execução, tanto faz rsrs, contanto que ela não esteja mais ativa...

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, **não é possível interromper threads**. O único jeito de uma thread terminar, é deixar o código dela executar até o final. O que você pode fazer, se a sua thread tiver um loop, é estabelecer um canal de comunicação com a thread, usando um mecanismo como `Queue`s, e fazer sua thread verificar esse canal dentro do loop. Então o seu programa principal pode usar o canal para enviar uma mensagem para a thread, que, quando verificar o canal, verá que deve parar o loop e encerrar.

Em outras palavras, você tem que escrever código para pedir a thread para suicidar, e se ela estiver ouvindo, ela o fará.

Sugiro evitar o uso de threads, no python quase não há vantagens em usar threads por causa do GIL. Use programação assíncrona, assim você pode controlar o momento da troca de contexto e portanto fazer estruturas paralelas mais canceláveis. Veja por exemplo este artigo (em inglês):

https://vorpus.org/blog/timeouts-and-cancellation-for-humans/